# Place a single label in multiple locations using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I'm some problem with my code and I don't know how I want to proceed. As you can see from my picture, I have different labels displaying the same text. I'm using the .place(x=##, y=##) to put them exactly where I want them. I feel like it's not very efficient to create/place a new label with the same text. I need to have the same labels (building width, length, eave, and the corresponding "FT" to move under the "Building 2" text. The entry boxes need to be labeled differently because I'm writing those values to different cells in excel, but the labels don't matter. Does anyone have a clue on how to paste 1 label at different locations? Yes I realize that some labels have .ttk while others have .tk I'm currently cleaning everything up.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have a clue on how to paste 1 label at different locations?

The answer is: you can't. You can't have a single widget in more than one place.